# Is it possible to compile a file have more then one classes without main method?

Tags: java, package

In java we create a java file which should match the class name underneath.
But if i want to have multiple classes in a single file and other class with main method in other java file.
How would i compile the first file, so that class with main method can use that code.

```
//File 1 A.java
package pack1;
public class A
{
 //code of A
}
public class B
{
 //code of B
}
//end of file A.java

 //File 2 C.java

import pack1.*;
class C extends A
{
  public static void main (String arg[])
 {
  A obj = new A();
 }
}
```

Please correct me if my assumtions are wrong wbout this hypothetical code situation.

Comment: You know about nested classes? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: @ppasler I know nested classes and abstract ver well, but please read my code example, the case where i just want put two different class in a single file and none of which have main method then how would i compile my code ?

Comment: @Prashant Kumar, Remove the public modifier from class B, as I don't see your class C extending it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, you can compile a java file as long as it has only 1 public
>   class/enum/interface.

The name of file should be same as that of the name of public class/enum/interface.

In first file there are two public classes, which is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you are right but unfortunately i am not able to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you what you want. It is impossible. You cann't declare two public classes in one file but you can declare calss into class. Like this:

```
//File 1 A.java
package pack1;
public class A
{
//Code of A
    public class B
    {
     //Code of B
    }
}
//end of file A.java

//File 2 C.java

import pack1.*;
class C extends A
{
    public static void main (String arg[])
    {
        A objA = new A();
        // If class C extends A
        B objB = new B();
        // else
        A.B objAB = new A.B();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right .
Is it possible if i could have one public class and other with difault access in a single file?

Comment: Sorry i forgot write public to class B

Comment: @Parshant Kmar `Is it possible if i could have one public class and other with difault access in a single file?` No this is impossible, becase in java name of file and class name must be equal.

Comment: Thanks, i understand now

Answer (score 0):

There can be only one Public class/enum/interface in a file and file name must be same as Public class/enum/interface.
It won't give you any error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Take a look at how Inheritance works with examples in this [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), especially the "An Example of Inheritance"

Just make sure that the name of the file is exactly the name of your class with the extension .java. E.g., if the public Class in your Java file is called "A", then your filename should be "A.java".